# How to delete duplicate calendar events when exporting sheets' data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, google-calendar-api

I want my Google Sheets to import to my Calendar anytime I edit column D. I've got a script that works, but it duplicates these entries. I want to delete all events with the same event name (column E). In simpler terms, anytime I edit column D, I want all calendar entries to be deleted and new ones added.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export Events",
    functionName : "addEvents"
  }];
  ss.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

function addEvents(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues(); 
  var data = ss.getRange("D2:E24").getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('k8kjmthm3fmcapidh9urkk6h2g@group.calendar.google.com');
  var calID = "k8kjmthm3fmcapidh9urkk6h2g@group.calendar.google.com";
  //Logger.log(cal);
  //Logger.log(data.length);

  for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
    if (i < headerRows) continue; 
    var column = data[i];
    var row = data[i];
    Logger.log(row);
    var date = row[0];
    //Logger.log(date);
    var title = row[1];
    var date = row[0];
    var id = row[1];
    var event = row[1]
    var eventSeries = row[1]
    var startDate = row[0]
    var endDate = row[0]

    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
      event.deleteEventSeries();
      row[1] = '';
      var event = cal.deleteEvent(row[1]);
    }
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log(event);
    }

    var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, startDate).getId();
    row[1] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
  }
}
```

Comment: `addMenu()` should be in `onOpen()`. And what is `debugger;` at the end of code?

Comment: @SangbokLee i'm a noob, so i just copied it. if i leave it out, it doesn't impact my code at all. i'll update the code with onOpen() for the menu, although, i'd prefer if the  calendar events exported/synced upon editing

Comment: i tried using the script from another site, but couldn't get it to work with my document. it worked fine on the test doc. it removes all events that don't match the spreadsheet (exactly what i want). i just need 2 columns (date, source) so i'm not sure how to edit dave's code to make it work on mine. any suggestions? https://github.com/Davepar/gcalendarsync/blob/master/gcalendarsync.js